# Get mime type with fileinfo, is the good method for big file?

Tags: memory, types, mime-types, mime, fileinfo

I would use fileinfo for get mime type of my files because mime_content_type is deprecated.
But I have a question, is it the good method for big file?

If I have a 1.5gb file, I don't want to "open" this file in memory for only get mime type...

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I suppose that finfo gets MIME informations from file header, so if you provide only very few file's first bytes it will work. I have tested this with a 3GB MKV file :

```
<?php
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
var_dump(
    $finfo->buffer(
        file_get_contents('My movie.mkv', false, null, -1, 1024),
        FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE
    )
);
```

It is returning :

```
string(16) "video/x-matroska"
```

So it worked !

Comment: With PHP7 I have observed a strange error with this method.

Return value with the whole file: ```image/jpeg; charset=binary``` but when using your method and only get the first 1024 bytes it returns ```application/octet-stream; charset=binary```. Same error when using the first 2048 or 4096 bytes

Comment: Which PHP7 version do you use ? I've tested with PHP version 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (Ubuntu Trusty) and it works as expected : `string(16) "video/x-matroska"`.
Which file are you testing ?